# Get dictionary mapping values to reference ID

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a list of numpy arrays like the following:

```
list_list = [np.array([53, 5, 2, 5, 5, 2, 1, 5, 9]), np.array([6, 4, 1,2, 53, 23, 1, 4])]
```

and a list of IDs for each array above:

```
ID = [6, 2]
```

How can I get a dictionary that for each unique value in `list_list`, I get a list of the IDs which contain it?

For example, for this very simple example, I want something like:

`{53: [6, 2], 5: [6], 2: [6, 2], 1: [6, 2], etc}`

My actual list_list is over 1000 lists long, with each numpy array containing around 10 million value, so efficiency in the solution is key.

I know that `dict(zip(ID, list_list))` will give me a dictionary corresponding an ID with all of its values, but it won't give me a value corresponding to IDs, which is what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: How does `53` map to `[6, 2]` but `5` maps to `[6]`? How do you determine this?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Sorry, should have been more clear. So 53 is a unique value from list_list, and it shows up in both IDs 6 and 2. However, 5 as a unique value in list_list only shows up in the first np array, which corresponds to ID #6. Like this, for every unique value in list_list, I want to see which corresponding ID it shows up in.

Comment: If I understand correctly, all values in `list_list[i]` correspond to `ID[i]`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes that is correct.

Comment: Shouldn't `2: [6]` be `2: [6, 2]`, if I'm not wrong (because `2` is in both sub lists)?

Comment: @Austin Yes, my bad. I will fix that in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to approach a problem like this is to break it into smaller steps. Describe these in a combination of English and pseudo-python as seems appropriate. You seem to have the right idea to get started with `zip(ID, list_list)`. This creates the association between the two lists as we discussed in the comments.

So what next? Well, we want to build a dictionary with the values in `list_list` as keys. To do so, we need to iterate over the list returned by `zip()`:

```
for id, list in zip(ID, list_list):
    pass
```

And then we need to iterate over the elements of `list` to determine the keys of the dictionary:

```
for id, list in zip(ID, list_list):
    for x in list:
        pass
```

Now we need an empty dictionary to add things to:

```
d = {}
for id, list in zip(ID, list_list):
    for x in list:
        pass
```

Next, we need to get a list for the dictionary if it exists. If it doesn't exist, we can use an empty list instead. Then append the `id` to the list and put it into the dictionary:

```
d = {}
for id, list in zip(ID, list_list):
    for x in list:
        l = d.get(x, [])
        l.append(id)
        d[x] = l
```

Notice how I describe in words what to do at each step and then translate it into Python. Breaking a problem into small steps like this is a key part of developing your skills as a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

We iterate the Zip(ID,list_list) and to get only the unique elements in the lis by creating a set of it.
Then we will iterate through this set and if that element is not allready present in the dictionary we add it to the dictionary if it's already present we append the id.

```
import numpy as np
list_list = [np.array([53, 5, 2, 5, 5, 2, 1, 5, 9]), np.array([6, 4, 1,2, 53, 23, 1, 4])]
ID = [6, 2]
dic={}
for id,lis in zip(ID,list_list):
    lis=set(lis)
    for ele in lis:
        if ele not in dic:
            dic[ele]=[id]
        else:
            dic[ele].append(id)

print(dic)

{1: [6, 2], 2: [6, 2], 5: [6], 9: [6], 53: [6, 2], 4: [2], 6: [2], 23: [2]}
```